# Приложение RocketLaunch

Tags: ios, swift

Делаю приложение, изначально белый экран с кнопкой и при нажатии на черную кнопку, у меня должно переходить на интерфейс с ракетой и облаками, но не переходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь я взял общую Rocket Content View и сделал её Hidden.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var rocketContentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var RocketImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var successLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func powerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        rocketContentView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно... Будьте добры, скиньте ссылку на архив. Попробую у себя посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте что связи внутри интерфейс билдера работают: откройте режим Xcode с одновременным просмотром Storyboard и кода вашего ViewController, наведите указатель мыши на точку входа IBOutlet и проследите что подсвечивается соответствующий графический элемент.
2. В интерфейс билдер выберите свой ViewController и включите правую панель инструментов (Inspector panel), в ней выведите на просмотр ваши Connections (Самая последняя вкладка Inspector - Show the connection Inspector) и убедитесь что у вас все seague подключены верно.
3. Добавьте в viewDidLoad строку предустановки скрытого состояния:
   rocketContentView.isHidden = true
4. Запустите приложение еще раз.